# UITableView clicked and no cell selected,but long press trigger cell selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

environment: Xcode 6.1.1 ;Storyboard 
issue：
    I'm creating some list with UITableView embed in a UIViewContrller instoryboard ,and all the cell can't be selected by click,but can be selected by long press unexpectedly.
    I don't know why and I can't figure it out .
    I hope someone help me .
    Thinks.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        HBillCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"billCell"];
        [cell loadInfo:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
        return cell; 
    }
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bill2detail" sender:nil];
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the delegate method: didSelectRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: Noone will help you as long as you don't show a bit of code...

Comment: @sasquatch Yes ,I'd linked the dataSource delegate and tableview delegate, and all the data can display correct,just only longpress can trigger didSelecteRowAtIndexPath to be called.

Comment: @grzegorz-krukowski The code is really simple .Just  :<pre><code>
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    HBillCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"billCell"];
    [cell loadInfo:self.dataSource[indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bill2detail" sender:nil];
}
</code></pre>

Comment: Do not put code in comments, it's hard to read. Edit your question to include properly formatted code.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause this problem. What are you doing in loadInfo:?

Comment: @rdelmar Just load data and display.That's why this problem makes me confused.All tableviews  in my storyboard got this problem ,I guess there's something wrong global.But I don't know what .

Answer (score 6):

Thank you all.This problem comes up because of the tap gesture added on the root view of view controller in the base class by myself.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapBlankAction:)];
    tgr.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
}
```

I'd figured it out.